# Is there something like an "app layout" in android?

Tags: android, layout

I'm explaining what I refer to with "app layout".

I'd like to call another app from android but at the same time staying in my own app, this can be visualized with having a border that would be from my own app and inside that border the app I'd like to call would be executing. New app would be then some sort of activity from original app.

The reason for doing this is that we'd like to keep always our app permanent meanwhile we can take advantage of apps that do perfectly some things that our app should do.

I think that if a web layout is possible so should be this, maybe it's not implemented or it would be pretty complicated to do, but it could be done.

Hope someone can guide me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box - no, that's not possible.

You can call other app activities with `startActivityForResult()` and have your app re-invoked  with result available in `onActivityResult()` callback when the activity finishes. The called activity will have its own UI and won't display in your app's frame.

If the called activity is your own and you can modify the code, you can make it dialog style with transparent margins/padding that show parts of your calling activity underneath.